# Trigger Intent from a List in Google Actions

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I am trying to create a Google action in which I want to invoke an intent when the user selects an object on the list. The problem is, there is only one event name 'actions_intent_OPTION' which will help in directing to a single intent. What I want is using the selected option I like to move to a particular intent.Is this possible. 
The existing google docs shows only the example where we modify our output speech with the option selected in that one intent(https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/helpers#getting_the_results_of_the_helper_1).

Comment: But why will want to do an intent for each option? As the example on the link you posted shows, you could call the action you need in the fulfillment after defining which option the user has selected.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I just wanted know whether there is any way through which I can map a list of intents to a list of options from my action.

Comment: I guess you could try to use context to do this: https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/nodejs/DialogflowApp#setContext

Comment: To be clear, do you have multiple sets of options, and you want each set to be handled by a different Intent? Or do you have the options, and you want each option to fire a different Intent?

Comment: Yes I want each option to fire a different intent

Comment: You're correct that the actions_intent_OPTION event will only map to a single action. But you can get the result of that intent with a webhook call (if using Node.js library - getSelectedOption), and then delegate fulfillment to some other intent handling logic.